# gdb step into functions until a breakpoint is reached

Tags: gdb

I am trying to trace function call made.

When running a gdb, i m adding a breakpoint say at line no "n"
I want to step into all function starting from line "n" to line "n+1"

Note:
Line n has internally many function calls

Please help me with this problem

Comment: "I want to step into all function" -- and what is stopping you from doing exactly that?

Comment: the code base is huge, i could not do it manually.

Comment: Here are the steps
1. Added a breakpoint at line no 3613
2. the code stopped at 3613
3. Added while loop
 while 1
 step
 end

This process runs for lifelong

What i want is i need to add another breakpoint at 3614 and i want to dump all function calls before hitting
the second breakpoint at 3614